# Using Spring EntityManager, Tests deadlock using DBCP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have a JPA project where we are migrating to use Spring Entity Manager instead of standard Hibernate. Currently we still manage our own transactions. When we moved over to Spring, and use DriverManagerDataSource for our tests all works (H2 in memory database), However, when we change to DBCP or c3p0, after the number of tests that equals the size of connection pools runs, the tests hang. 
We are calling close using Try with Resources.

Here is some of our application Context:

```
<bean id="inMemoryDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
      p:username="sa"
      p:password=""
      p:maxTotal="10"
      p:logAbandoned="true"
      p:removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      p:removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true">
</bean>

<alias name="inMemoryDataSource" alias="connectionDataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="connectionDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
              p:showSql="false"
              p:generateDdl="false"
              p:database="H2"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thread Dump:

```
2014-11-16 17:08:26,644 DEBUG [main] access.TransactionalDataAccessLayer(67): Closing entity manager
2014-11-16 17:08:29
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode):

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000a72a800 nid=0x3fac runnable [0x000000000c56e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
      - locked <0x00000007ded9cfb8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
      at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
      at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
      at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
      - locked <0x00000007ded9cfb8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
      at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:88)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000a6cd800 nid=0x3ccc runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a6c6800 nid=0x2e64 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a6c5000 nid=0x40c0 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a69e000 nid=0x3ec runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a69b000 nid=0xfe8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x00000000023a0800 nid=0x4350 in Object.wait() [0x000000000ba2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      - waiting on <0x00000007824e29b8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
      - locked <0x00000007824e29b8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000000a694000 nid=0x32dc in Object.wait() [0x000000000b92f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      - waiting on <0x00000007824e2630> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
      - locked <0x00000007824e2630> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022b8800 nid=0xf24 waiting on condition [0x000000000229d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
      - parking to wait for  <0x0000000781cca690> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
      at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:524)
      at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:438)
      at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
      at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:119)
      at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1413)
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
      at com.intel.aa.smoove.access.TransactionalDataAccessLayer.execute(TransactionalDataAccessLayer.java:47)
      at com.intel.aa.smoove.access.TestDataAccessCalibration.findCalibrationById(TestDataAccessCalibration.java:59)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
      at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
      at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
      at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
      at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
      at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
      at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
      at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
      at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
      at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000000a691800 nid=0x42d8 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022cf000 nid=0x245c runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d0800 nid=0x3efc runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d2800 nid=0x4310 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022d5000 nid=0x2248 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x000000000a711800 nid=0x1324 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 205

Heap
PSYoungGen      total 279552K, used 160467K [0x00000007d5d00000, 0x00000007e7b00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 266240K, 56% used [0x00000007d5d00000,0x00000007df043de8,0x00000007e6100000)
  from space 13312K, 72% used [0x00000007e6e00000,0x00000007e7770ed8,0x00000007e7b00000)
  to   space 13312K, 0% used [0x00000007e6100000,0x00000007e6100000,0x00000007e6e00000)
ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 15300K [0x0000000781800000, 0x0000000786c00000, 0x00000007d5d00000)
  object space 86016K, 17% used [0x0000000781800000,0x00000007826f12c0,0x0000000786c00000)
PSPermGen       total 36352K, used 36317K [0x000000077c600000, 0x000000077e980000, 0x0000000781800000)
  object space 36352K, 99% used [0x000000077c600000,0x000000077e977478,0x000000077e980000)
```

Comment: This reads as a statement. What is the question you want answered?

Comment: I assume that he wants to know how to make the tests work? "However, when we change to DBCP or c3p0, after the number of tests that equals the size of connection pools runs, the tests hang.". I assume he wants to un-hang them :)

Comment: I wonder how you run your tests? How are your application contexts managed?

Comment: We load the applicationContext using SpringJunitRunner

Comment: and when you say "hang", what about printing a thread dump?

Comment: Here is my thread dump:

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to complete the migration to Spring by using Spring transaction management and remove all our self(hibernate) managed transactions.